# Can I use a certificate that will allow PHP connect to sybase vs. using an account/password?

Tags: php, certificate, sybase

One of are programmers thinks that we can have PHP connect the the sybase database without using an account/password by using a certificate.  Currently we are using odbc_connect, etc. to connect and query the database in PHP.  I seen there there is an option to use certificates for mysql database (they have a different set of functions that use the certificate) but we are using sybase, not mysql.  So is this possible?  If so, where would I go to read about how to do this

Comment: You don't mention which Sybase database you mean but some support kerberos which allows access without a username and password. For Adaptive Server Enterprise this does however require an additional licence - more info here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/sag1768.htm

Comment: Kerbose does allow the web page to be trusted so PHP can connect without an account or password, but there seems to be a lot of overhead to setting kerbose.  I will talk to my SA and see what he has to say about setting up kerbose and maintaining it, etc.  and using this to connect $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={$driver};Server=$serverName;Port=$port;Database=$databaseName;Trace=Yes;TraceFile=/tmp/tdb.log", Trusted_Connection=yes; ).   But this seems like a lot of work use to not use a read only account on a trust, closed network.

Comment: Our Sybase server and clients are running Sybase ASE 16.0 SP02 PL08.

Comment: Yeah you need to code around the instantiation of a keytab for connection and also depending on your keytab settings some long-running batch processes could need extra checks to ensure its renewed correctly if the connection to the database isn't maintained throughout. The cost of the Security & Directory Services option to use Kerberos could also be a big factor - if you don't already have it in your license agreement it's not cheap but it does also then allow you to use SSL to connect into Sybase as well for additional web security and also encryption in the database.

Comment: I have talked to our SA and Task Lead and the SA doesn't want to do it but Task Lead does since this would fall under "security enhancement".  She doesn't want any account/passwords saved in files that can be read by other people.  Our SA is checking with the head SA for the department, if he says yes, then Kerbose will be used.  Personally, I think this is a lot of work for read only password account that I was created to connect to sybase.

Comment: It is extra work for sure but if you have the security license you can do full database level encryption (SAP's equivalent of Transparent Database Encryption (TDE)) which means data is fully encrypted at rest on disk, which can be a big win to some audit teams and in fact is mandatory in some locations so it does have other benefits :)